# Office365 Graph API: Fetch Calendar Share Permissions

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm trying to extract the share permissions for a [Calendar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/calendar?view=graph-rest-beta) through Microsoft Graph (or even the old Outlook REST API) but it seems that there is no Graph endpoint to get a calendar's sharing permissions.

When fetching a calendar's details, the closest I found was `isShared` on the Calendar resource - but that doesn't give me the full data I see from the Web UI:

[image: Calendar's sharing permissions]

Basically, trying to receive the equivalent of [Google Calendar's ACL](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/acl/list) list.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this works for you:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-calendarpermissions?view=graph-rest-1.0

It's limited to accounts with some administrative rights though.
If you query the permissions with a "normal" user's account, you just get a `method not supported` error message instead.

Which is how I found that one, as I was trying to make my app aware, whenever or not it has the permissions to create and delete it's own events in a shared calendar.
But the Endpoint refuses to respond to normal users, so it's completely useless to my use case.

But maybe it works in yours. Should you still need it, 3 years since asking...
I'm more leaving this for others who might run into this.

Comment: Good Samaritan 
No longer relevant, but thanks for helping others! :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot share the calendar through the graph api, or open a calendar from some other user that they shared with you, there is no point in showing the ACL.

You might have better luck using the Exchange Web Service (or EWS) they do have those properties on folders. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/folders-and-items-in-ews-in-exchange

Or if you really need it in the graph api (since the EWS is no longer the recommended way to talk to Office 365) you can create a ticket on [UserVoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests) (if it doesn't exist already).